# How can I ignore notifications for @everyone and @here for all Slack channels?

Tags: notifications, slack

How can I ignore notifications for @everyone and @here for all Slack channels?

I know that this can be configured for each channel but and looking for just 1 setting for all Slack channels, as it tedious to configure for all channels.

[image]